# Database commit over Github

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, github, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Github plugin on Visual Studio and once I commit the whole project I cannot see (on my second computer) the SQL database that I have on the "main" computer.

In other words, how can I share the SQL database to other participants?

Comment: Is it an embedded database (i.e. sql compact) or a server?

Comment: It is SQL Server inside Visual Studio